# Sorting data on the basis of values in the row and then printing the same

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

I want to find out the columns where

A. if all three values are positive, then row 1 is greater than row 2.
B. Similarly, if all three values r negative, then row 1 is less than row 2.

Then I want to print the list of all such companies (i.e column heads).

Kindly help. Will be thankful.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: And add expected output too ;) Welcome to SO.